# Raise TypeError when adding new column to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I've been watching an online course about data analysis using Python. I came across a problem when following exactly what the instructor did. Basically, I pulled a data frame called "flights" from seaborn and set the index "year" and "month" and unstacked it. The following codes are used:

```
import seaborn
import pandas as pd
flights = seaborn.load_dataset("flights")
flights_indexed = flights.set_index(["year","month"])
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()
flights_unstacked
```

[the final data frame is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Iy7.png)

Then I am trying to add a new column called "Total" at the end for the sum of each year using the following code:

```
flights_unstacked["passengers"]["Total"] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis = 1)
```

But it raised a `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category.`

I am new to data manipulation using pandas. Anyone can tell me how to fix this? Is this a version issue, because the online instructor did exactly the same thing but his works just fine. PS: I use Python 2.7 and pandas 0.20.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `seaborn.load_dataset` line detects the `month` column as a `category` data type. To get around this error, cast `categorical` to `str` with this line right after `flights = seaborn.load_dataset("flights")`:

```
flights["month"] = flights["month"].astype(str)
```

To sort the month strings in chronological order, first drop the top level (level=0) of the columns of `flights_unstacked` (this level holds the single value `passengers`):

```
import seaborn
import pandas as pd

flights = seaborn.load_dataset("flights")
flights["month"] = flights["month"].astype(str)

flights_indexed = flights.set_index(["year", "month"])
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()
flights_unstacked.columns = flights_unstacked.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Then reindex the month-string columns according to a list of month strings that you pre-built in chronological order:

```
import calendar
months = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1, 13)]
flights_unstacked = flights_unstacked[months]
```

Finally, you can add a column of totals:

```
flights_unstacked["Total"] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
In [329]: flights_unstacked
Out[329]:
month  January  February  March  April  May  June  July  August  September  October  November  December  Total
year                                                                                                          
1949       112       118    132    129  121   135   148     148        136      119       104       118   1520
1950       115       126    141    135  125   149   170     170        158      133       114       140   1676
1951       145       150    178    163  172   178   199     199        184      162       146       166   2042
1952       171       180    193    181  183   218   230     242        209      191       172       194   2364
1953       196       196    236    235  229   243   264     272        237      211       180       201   2700
1954       204       188    235    227  234   264   302     293        259      229       203       229   2867
1955       242       233    267    269  270   315   364     347        312      274       237       278   3408
1956       284       277    317    313  318   374   413     405        355      306       271       306   3939
1957       315       301    356    348  355   422   465     467        404      347       305       336   4421
1958       340       318    362    348  363   435   491     505        404      359       310       337   4572
1959       360       342    406    396  420   472   548     559        463      407       362       405   5140
1960       417       391    419    461  472   535   622     606        508      461       390       432   5714
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've slightly modified your answer?

Comment: Thank you for the help. But it seems that the unstack method automatically sorts the month names as they are now string instead of categorical type. Is there any way to fix this since I still want the month names in the original order. Also, is there a way to cast the type of the month column right before the unstack method so that I won't change anything about the original dataset "flights". Thank you.

Comment: @MaxU, no problem at all. Thanks for improving the answer!

Comment: @richard, I've edited my answer to sort the month columns in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  The final statement still gave me "SettingWithCopyWarning" warning hence had to switch off Copy Warning `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
flights_unstacked["Total"] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)`